# How to Parse a list of tuples with different number of key values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of `tuples` like this.

```
('change', ['System.Rev', 'newValue'], (1, 2))
('add', ['System.Rev'], [('oldValue', 1)])
('change', ['System.AuthorizedDate', 'newValue'], ('2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z'))
('add', ['System.AuthorizedDate'], [('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z')])
('change', ['System.RevisedDate', 'newValue'], ('2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z', '9999-01-01T00:00:00Z'))
('add', ['System.RevisedDate'], [('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z')])
('change', ['System.ChangedDate', 'newValue'], ('2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z'))
('add', ['System.ChangedDate'], [('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z')])
('change', ['System.Watermark', 'newValue'], (249, 250))
('add', ['System.Watermark'], [('oldValue', 249)])
('add', '', [('Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority', {'newValue': 599975506.0})])
```

Is there a way to convert this into a dictionary or some other way to parse this so I can get the `add` and `change` values?

Expected Output

`change` `System.Rev` `newValue` `2`

`add` `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority` `newValue': 599975506.0`
or something similar which can show the values added and changed in a clean format to be sent to
`db`  Columns.

This is how I am getting this

```
from dictdiffer import diff

for i, j in enumerate(rev_items):
    try:
        res = list(diff(rev_items[i], rev_items[i+1]))
        for item in res:
            print(item)
```

when I do `dict(res)` it prints nothing.

One way I tried was this.
Not using list comprehension

```
for item in res:
    for c in range(len(item)):
        print(item[c])
```

which outputs this

```
change
['System.Rev', 'newValue']
(1, 2)
add
['System.Rev']
[('oldValue', 1)]
change
['System.AuthorizedDate', 'newValue']
('2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z')
add
['System.AuthorizedDate']
[('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z')]
change
['System.RevisedDate', 'newValue']
('2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z', '9999-01-01T00:00:00Z')
add
['System.RevisedDate']
[('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z')]
change
['System.ChangedDate', 'newValue']
('2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z')
add
['System.ChangedDate']
[('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z')]
change
['System.Watermark', 'newValue']
(249, 250)
add
['System.Watermark']
[('oldValue', 249)]
add

[('Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority', {'newValue': 599975506.0})]
```

How to get/parse the `add` and `change` values out of this?

Comment: I didn't vote, but that's not a list of tuples. A list is contained inside `[...]`

Comment: It's not clear how your expected output relates to the input. Why is the new value only `2`, not `(1, 2)`?

Comment: What is `revs`? Why not just `for value in response['value']:`?

Comment: `rev_items[i+1]` will get an error on the last iteration.

Comment: What is `diff()`? There's a `diff()` method in pandas and numpy, but it's not a standard Python function.

Comment: @Barmar   Kindly see this `list(diff(rev_items[i], rev_items[i+1]))` . It is a `list`. I am comparing two dictionaries for values added or changed. As I mentioned..The output doesn't need to be exactly like in the question. Just something that shows what changed and can be sent to a DB Column and doesn't end up becomine one-to-many type situation. I put it in a `try` block to avoid the last iteration error

Comment: @Barmar Yes the `diff` is not a standard python library. It gives out a `generator` object which I converted to a list. `from dictdiffer import diff` . I am using `dictdiffer` a utility to make comparing dictionaries easier.

Comment: `revs` is the number of dictionaries I get in a previous step. If it is more than 1 dictionaries then the comparison happens. This is all from Azure Board and this data is for the work items..just in case you are familiar with that.

Comment: You should put that import line in the question so it's clear.

Comment: @Barmar . Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: So what you showed at the beginning is the output of the `diff()`, not the original data?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. It is the result of comparison of the dictionaries which becomes a list of the shown `tuples`. These are the new values that have been added/changed.

Comment: `for i in range(len(rev_items)-1):` will avoid the last iteration error.

Comment: What do you want the final dict to look like? You have duplicate keys `add` and `change`, you can't have duplicate keys in a dict.

Comment: It seems like your main question is about how to flatten all the nested tuples and dictionaries in the `diff` results?

Comment: No.  There won't be duplicate keys. Yes..Just something I can send to a column called `added`  OR `changed` and it is just 1 value. `(1,2)` is fine.

Comment: Please update the question to show what you want the result to really look like as data, and show how you've tried to solve it yourself. SO is not a code-writing service, we help you fix your code.

Comment: @Barmar I avoided that to keep the question short.

Comment: We don't need to see where the data came from, that's irrelevant to solving your actual problem.

Comment: @Barmar It cleared the `list` confusion. Adding some code in the previous steps usually helps has been my experience. That is why I added it.

Comment: Start with the main code with the problem. If the previous steps are necessary to clarify, you can add that as well.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question. It seems simpler now. Just need to convert this into a `dict` is all I can think of, but I don't know how.

Comment: You keep saying you want to make this into a dict. What should the dict keys and values be?

Comment: The argument to `dict()` should be a sequence of key-value pairs. You don't seem to have any unique keys.

Comment: But then they will all be duplicate keys. `add` and `change`. I only said dictionary because I thought it would be easier to get the values from it, using the keys. Seems I am wrong about that. Well, then that is the issue.

Comment: Please show what you actually want the results to be? Why not just `results.append(res)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239919/discussion-between-abhishek-rai-and-barmar).

Comment: @Barmar Got a clean enough output. Posted the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to inputs from [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar). This is how I got it.

```
res = list(diff(rev_items[i], rev_items[i+1]))
for item in res:
    for a, b in enumerate(item):
        if item[a] == 'change' or item[a] == 'add':
            print(item[a+1], ":", item[a+2])
```

Output

```
['System.Rev', 'newValue'] : (1, 2)
['System.Rev'] : [('oldValue', 1)]
['System.AuthorizedDate', 'newValue'] : ('2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z')
['System.AuthorizedDate'] : [('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z')]
['System.RevisedDate', 'newValue'] : ('2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z', '9999-01-01T00:00:00Z')
['System.RevisedDate'] : [('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z')]
['System.ChangedDate', 'newValue'] : ('2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.77Z')
['System.ChangedDate'] : [('oldValue', '2021-10-27T11:10:45.047Z')]
['System.Watermark', 'newValue'] : (249, 250)
['System.Watermark'] : [('oldValue', 249)]
 : [('Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority', {'newValue': 599975506.0})]
```